# SharePoint application asking user details after three time showing blank page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In a SharePoint two server form, When I am accessing web application
URL showing black page after three times with admin user but I am able
to access CA URL. In second SP server able to access web
application and CA without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is couple of common causes of it.

1. Loopback check. You will need to modify the registry keys: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0 
   REF: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926642
2. lack of SuperReader/SuperUser configured. 
   REF: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758656.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396